# AppCompat Toolbar showing an unwanted settings button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, xamarin, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I just started using toolbar instead of actionbar in my android app. But it shows a ridiculous settings button at the bottom of the screen and i couldn't find a way to erase it. Please help me with this.

Here is a screenshot for you to understand the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Gwe.png

Here is my code:

```
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main_Activity_Container);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.Toolbar);
        var toolbarBottom = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.BottomToolbar);

        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportActionBar.Title = "Hello from Toolbar";
        SetSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(false);
        toolbarBottom.Title = "";
        toolbarBottom.InflateMenu (Resource.Menu.tabs);
        toolbarBottom.MenuItemClick += delegate(object sender, Toolbar.MenuItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this,
                "Bottom toolbar pressed: " + e.Item.TitleFormatted, duration:    ToastLength.Short).Show();
            indeterminateVisible = !indeterminateVisible;
            SetSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(indeterminateVisible);
        };
```

axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/BottomToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/Toolbar"
    android:layout_above="@id/BottomToolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme"  parent ="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
  <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#24598a</item>
  <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
  <item name="android:minWidth">70dip</item>
  <item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>
  <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>
</style>
```

tabs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      local:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Edit" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      local:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Undo" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      local:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Redo" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      local:showAsAction="always"
      android:title="Save" />
```

I also want to change the positions of these menu items. I know that i can use custom components inside of toolbars but i don't get why these menu items always appear in the right hand side. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by following below steps :

First of all to remove the disgusting settings button at bottom do the following :

In your activity, comment getMenuInflater().inflate(...) :

```
....

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_map, menu);
    return true;
}

....
```

This will surely remove settings button from bottom, it did mine.

Now you can create your own menu items as normal views, add as many buttons as you want in your toolbar, whereever you want, see an example :

Toolbar is just a ViewGroup, So, in your toolbar.xml file or whereever you have defined android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, change as per your requirements of buttons and their positions.

Below shows how to add an button at the center of toolbar, you can change it to your required position :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="@drawable/color_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="button"
    android:onClick="buttonHandler"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but deleting menu inflater code doesn't change anything for me. I think, this is an OS or device specific behaviour, when i run my code on OS 4.1.1 emulator I didn't see that settings button. By the way, screenshot is from htc one x os 4.2.2

Comment: You are right htc one has it by default, have a look at this link : http://www.androidcentral.com/how-get-rid-screen-menu-bar-htc-one-android-42

Comment: Yes that worked. Actually, this only solved the problem for my test phone but it is a device specific behaviour and I think there is no universal solution. So this is not going to be a problem I guess. Thanks

Comment: This answer solved the problem for me. And it drew my attention to the menu resource file that was defining the Settings button, which I had forgotten about.